# HBase is able to connect to ZooKeeper but the connection closes immediately

Tags: connection, hbase

i'm running a hadoop project for four to five days,then an error from hbase : HBase is able to connect to ZooKeeper but the connection closes immediately. This could be a sign that the server has too many connections (30 is the default). Consider inspecting your ZK server logs for that error and then make sure you are reusing HBaseConfiguration as often as you can. See HTable's javadoc for more information.
Please give me some suggestion. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Check your zookeeper config. ZooKeeper has a setting to limit the number of connections from a single ip address and you may need to modify that (if that is indeed the problem). the setting is called maxClientCnxns